# relationship for database Column type object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have strange column with object records like this:
[image]

I have troubled with relation with user object (data column)

here is my Temp model:

```
class Temp extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function temp()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Temp');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$data['mediaReport'] = Temp::where('type', 'media_report')->paginate(10);
```

View:

```
@foreach ($mediaReport as $m)
    <?php $wer = json_decode($m->data); ?>
    <td><span class="bg-primary-700 text-highlight">{{ $wer->id }}</span></td>
    <td align="center">{{ $wer->comment }}</td>
    <td><span><a href="{{ route('profile', $wer->user->username) }}" class="bg-success-700 text-highlight">Reporter</a></span> <span><a href="#" class="bg-danger-700 text-highlight">{{-- {{ $m->id }} --}}Delete</a></span></td>
@endforeach
```

I got error "Trying to get property of non-object", this error in "$wer->user->username" can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you decode the JSON from your **data** column, the **$wer->user** value is a **string** containing user ID, that's why you're getting error when trying to access **username** property of that string.

In order for it to work, you'd need to fetch the user first, e.g.:

```
<a href="{{ route('profile', User::findOrFail($wer->user)->username) }}">
```

That't the easiest, but not the cleanest solution. **The view should just render the data, not decode JSON or load data from the DB** - you should do that somewhere in your model creation logic or controller.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I dont know how to do it in model